# Not being able to invoke servlet from the jsp page using web.xml

Tags: jsp, servlets

Here is the sample web.xml code :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Registration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

While opening the page Registration on my browser(am using tomcat 7.0),it shows the error :

> The requested resource (/yaman/proj/Registration) is not available. (404 error)

Even when i remove all the files from the class folder,it says the same,as expected.
Cant identify where exactly does the problem lie.
Please help!

Comment: Do you have `RegisterServlet.class` class inside `WEB-INF` ?

Comment: yes,i do..have double checked every spelling and stuff too!

Comment: You do need to mention fully qualified class name in the `servlet-class`. Have you done that?

Comment: i resolved it.was an error with apache.

Comment: Great! You should include your answer here(not in the question, but as an answer). This will help others who face similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a really weird error,and i have no idea why it happened.
All my files for my project were listed under webapps/yaman/proj/ ..when i was using tomcat to register myself using a register.jsp page(which was intern mapped to a servlet using web.xml),it gave me a 404 error,saying the resource is not available.
But when i cut and paste all the files from "proj",copied it to "yaman" and deleted "proj",it somehow worked and the servlets also worked fine.
I have no idea why such an error arised.
If any of you folks have an idea why this happened or experienced same sort of problem,feel free to add comments.